# how to use sql where condition on comma separated value

Tags: sql

```
| id | name    | numbers        |
+----+---------+----------------+
| 1  | arjun   | 62,45,68,95,50 |
| 2  | yuvaraj | 45,65,85,68    |
| 3  | sahadev | 45,65,85,68    |
| 4  | yogi    | 45,65,85,68    |
| 5  | krishna | 45,65,85,68    |
```

I want id data where number is 45

I tried

```
select * 
from table 
where number=45
```

but it doesn't work.

Comment: Please try to make your question readable. This is very difficult to understand at the moment. Formatting your question well is important.

Comment: Because you don't have any records where `number = 45`.  You're storing multiple values in the same field in your data.  Don't do that.  Create a second table with a foreign key back to this table and add multiple *records* to that table, each storing one of the `number` values for this record.  It's called "normalizing the data" and it's what relational databases were designed to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With `like`:

```
select * from table where concat(',', numbers, ',') like concat('%,', '45',',%')
```

because you need to transform the column's value to something like this:

```
,45,65,85,68,
```

and then apply `like` to the pattern `'%,45,%'`.

Answer (score 0):

You can try using like operator

```
select * from table where number like '%45%'
```

or you can use find_in_set() for mysql database

```
select * from table where find_in_set(45,number)>0
```

Comment: it's work, thank sir.  but if there are number 450 or something belonge to 45  than gone wrong, give any solution please

Comment: @fa06 please remove first sql query as it is wrong as Salman explained

Answer (score 0):

using like operator with pattern as '%45%':

```
select * from table where numbers like '%45%'
```

Comment: can you select fa06 answer as correct one as he came to the answer before me(I missed that answer due to edit work)?

Comment: Look at his comment. It matches 450, 4500, 945 etc.

Comment: Sorry Didnt see that error coming.
I just tried with only the outputs he gave.

Answer (score 0):

If you use like operator it will get all the records having 45 (like 345 or 12245 or 65445). if you want records having values exactly "45" You can try the below code if you are using SQL Server 2016 or higher versions.

```
select * from (
SELECT * FROM tablename
cross apply
STRING_SPLIT('numbers',',') )a where value='45'
```

Answer (score 0):

For Postgres you can use:

```
select *
from the_table
where '45' = any(string_to_array(numbers, ','));
```